# Ubuntu not recognizing igpu

Tags: drivers, 22.04, intel-graphics

I'm trying to get QuickSync to work on my intel 4570T but when I have everything ready to get transcoding, Ubuntu only lists llvmpipe as my graphics. I can't seem to get Ubuntu to recognize the iGPU as a HD4600, it instead is listed as a Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th gen. I've tried to do software updates as well as full-upgrade but I can't seem to get further. I've posted pictures showing my issue.

I remote into the PC via rdp with windows with xorg in case that matters at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

[lshw -class display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaMJu.png)

[llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X7j1.png)

Comment: I don't see any problem here. You've got a desktop environment running, so it's clear that your system is using a GPU. The "i" in iGPU stands for integrated. That means that it's actually running off the Intel CPU and is not a dedicated graphics processor. Intel iGPUs are supported at the kernel level and don't need any end user intervention to work properly. And it will not usually identify the exact model or family name of the chip. Maybe you are just expecting to see it identified differently? Is there actually a problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Potentially. But I've compared to others' lshw and system info and it's typically displayed correctly for them. Also when I run 'Intel_cpu_top' it never shows usage in terms of video encoding despite verifying in my Plex dashboard that transcoding was occuring, not direct play.

This led me to believe that it must be either a deprecated driver or a bad initial install and llvmpipe is a fallback for a desktop environment.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying that Plex is working as expected, or that it isn't. If something is not working correctly, then you should ask about your actual problem instead of asking about something tangential that you think might be the problem. So far, I can't tell if you're describing an actual problem. What you've identified as a problem doesn't add up. You're running a DE so it's clear that the system is using the GPU. There aren't any alternative drivers for Intel iGPUs-- it's supported at the kernel level. It should either work, or it doesn't; and it appears to be working.